# Unlocked Package Custom Metadata SubscriberControlled not working

Tags: custom-metadata, unmanaged-package, unlocked-package

I have an unlocked package that uses custom metadata to store settings (Shipment_Setting__mdt).

XML of the Shipment_Setting__mdt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<label>Shipment Setting</label>
<pluralLabel>Shipment Settings</pluralLabel>
<visibility>Public</visibility>
</CustomObject>
```

**Shipment_Setting__mdt** has the following fields:

**Mapping__c** - DeveloperControlled

**Value__c** - SubscriberControlled

XML of the Value__c field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<fullName>value__c</fullName>
<externalId>false</externalId>
<fieldManageability>SubscriberControlled</fieldManageability>
<label>value</label>
<length>255</length>
<required>false</required>
<type>Text</type>
<unique>false</unique>
</CustomField>
```

The package is installed in a sandbox and I can change the Value__c as expected on the Shipment_Setting__mdt records.

The problem is that when I install an updated version of the package, it overwrites all the Value__c fields with a blank value (blank is the default value in the package).

In the Salesforce documentation it states that SubscriberControlled fields will not change value from a package upgrade.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is it stated in SF Documentation that Sub. Controlled fields are not changed? I found this (old) that says otherwise: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XcdHQAS

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_package_access.htm&type=5

Subscriber Org If a field is subscriber controlled, subscribers can also change the value in their own org. If the record is in a managed package, the new field value is propagated only to Subscriber Org new package subscribers. Existing subscribers that upgrade to the latest version of the package do not get the new field value.

Comment: I'll see if I can find some docs, but know this: Unlocked Packages are *not* Managed Packages. Just because you find documentation saying that "Managed Packages behaves like *xyz*," does **not** in any way imply that this same behavior applies to Unlocked Packages.